Unable to Delete Latest Item from Python Program List
Description: In my Python program, I have a "Delete" button to remove the latest item added, but clicking the button does not remove the item. We are using Tkinter for creating the GUI of our program.
Steps Taken:
Used the DeleteLatestMenu() function to remove the latest item from the allmenu variable and update the table.
The "Delete" button in my program is set to call DeleteLatestMenu().
Issue: Even though I click the "Delete" button, the latest item is not removed from the table.
Related Code:
def DeleteLatestMenu():
    global allmenu
    if allmenu:
        latest_item = list(allmenu.keys())[-1]
        del allmenu[latest_item]
        table.delete(*table.get_children())
        UpdateTable()
        new_total = sum(item[3] for item in allmenu.values())
        v_total.set('{:.2f}'.format(new_total))

B_delete_latest = ttk.Button(T3, text='Delete', command=DeleteLatestMenu)
B_delete_latest.place(x=670, y=480)

Question: What should I do to ensure that the latest item is removed from the table when I click the "Delete" button in my GUI?
I tried implementing a function called DeleteLatestMenu() that should remove the latest item from a list (allmenu) and update a table accordingly when clicking a "Delete" button in a Tkinter GUI. Specifically, the function deletes the latest item from the allmenu dictionary, updates the table to reflect the changes, and recalculates the total.
I expected that when clicking the "Delete" button, the latest item would be removed from the table and the total would be recalculated accurately. However, despite clicking the button, the latest item remains in the table, and the total is not updated as expected.

Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example of your problem

At least you need to post the code of UpdateTable() and sample data for allmenu.
